# Matching 'whole text only' using expect

Tags: expect

I am trying to match a string in expect programming as mentioned below

```
send "cd $tftproot/cmbuild\r"
expect \\$
send "ls -lrt\r"

expect -ex "10.0.1.10000-2" {
      send "touch $builddir\r"
      expect \\$
  }
```

In the specified directory there is an another file with name **10.0.1.10000-24**. The expect command **expect -ex "10.0.1.10000-2"** is matching with the file **10.0.1.10000-24** and is getting passed.

I have even tried with **expect -exact "10.0.1.10000-2"** and **expect "10.0.1.10000-2"**, both commands are getting passed.

I want to match with the exact string(**10.0.1.10000-2**) that i am passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many ways. Assume your file will always be the one which will be listed at last in that directory like as follows,

```
/var/root # ls -lrt                                                             
total 4                                                                         
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root           242 Nov 12 10:08 hello.c                
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             9 Nov 12 10:08 dos -> /root/dos                  
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 12 10:08 10.0.1.10000-24
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Nov 12 10:08 10.0.10000-2        
/var/root #
```

Then you can use the pattern as

```
expect  "10.0.1.10000-2$" {
      send "touch $builddir\r"
      expect \\$
  }
```

If your file can be in between any entries, then matching a newline `\n`

```
expect "10.0.1.10000-2\n" {
      send "touch $builddir\r"
      expect \\$
  }
```

or matching a white-space character `\s`

```
expect "10.0.1.10000-2\s+" {
          send "touch $builddir\r"
          expect \\$
      }
```

can be used based on your requirement.

To avoid this confusion, you could have use `ls 10.0.1.10000-2` directly, which would be better and you can get the output, only if it is matching that name.

**Update :**

There is one more easy way available. We can make use of word boundaries ( `\m` and `\M` ).

```
expect "10.0.1.10000-2\M" {
              send "touch $builddir\r"
              expect \\$
          }
```

`\m` matches only at the start of a word. That is, it matches at any position that has a non-word character to the left of it, and a word character to the right of it. It also matches at the start of the string if the first character in the string is a word character. `\M` matches only at the end of a word. It matches at any position that has a word character to the left of it, and a non-word character to the right of it. It also matches at the end of the string if the last character in the string is a word character.